# Magento Rest API - oAuth Error

Tags: php, magento, rest, oauth

I am working with Magento Rest API for the first time, i went through the tutorials of Rest API on `http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest` and tried one example to fetch product through API:

```
$callbackUrl = "http://localhost/wineshop/products.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://localhost/wineshop/oauth/initiate?     oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://localhost/wineshop/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://localhost/wineshop/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://localhost/wineshop/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'u48p1x9gzrg7r82c94woa5z7g805uw0i';
$consumerSecret = '96ydrk8s89xxath8h5z71vcl5abfq0zg';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
$_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
$authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret,  OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
$oauthClient->enableDebug();
```

I've also installed the latest version of OAUTH and it also shows in my WampServer PHP Extensions but it doesn't show in `phpinfo()`. I coped the `php_oauth.dll` file into `..\www\bin\php\ext` and i also edited `php.ini` and entered `extension=php_oauth.dll` but on running the `products.php` it shows me the

```
Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in P:\wamp\www\products.php on line 19
```

And i also want to know that how to request for the token i've got `key` and `secret` after entering new consumer in Magento Admin Panel. But i don't know how to get `Access Token` & `Access Token Secret` that we enter in `RESTClient`

Please Help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

reason for fatal error is **oauth** library is not installed. following step to install library

1) get the package from http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

2) search for oauth and choose the one for your machine

3) Put that .dll file in your PHP extensions directory.

4) Find the extensions area in your php.ini file and add this to it:

[PHP_OAUTH]
extension=php_oauth.dll

restart your server

after solving fatal error if help is required then check http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html for magento REST API

use the sample code given in above link its is used for get Access Token & Access Token Secret etc. you have to just run php file

Comment: I am using on live server this code, show error  `Class 'OAuth' not found`