# How to get Request Token from Magento REST API?

Tags: api, magento

I am using Magento CE edition and i want to access the REST API of magento through REST Client oR Java client. I have Consumer Key and sceret. When i am trying to execute 
/oauth/initiate i am getting following response
oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_consumer_key.

I am refering the following link for execution
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/authentication/oauth_authentication.html

Can anyone please let me know how we test the API through the REST client and how we get the access_token.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789938/magento-rest-api-oauth-error/19678803#19678803

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483875/magento-rest-api-error-500/19677476#19677476