# Retrieving oauth token from Magento REST API

Tags: java, magento, rest, oauth, scribe

I need your help.
I need to connect to my Magento store using REST but I have a problem to retrieve the oauth token.
I did what was said in this tutorial : gmartinezgil.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/using-the-magento-rest-api-in-java-with-scribe/
My code is available here : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zglzl9xsxcjrpid/lGrZNYfRzG

I'm working with Magento 1.8.1.0 using Wampserver

Here is my Main.java file:

```
package foo;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.*;
/**
 * @author jerry
 */
public final class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String MAGENTO_API_KEY = "r0ntsryd0hamwmdnjezb8joun01c4h1s";
        final String MAGENTO_API_SECRET = "czylgk8yxhkvrx141v1q9trx0iw4qbgt";
        final String MAGENTO_REST_API_URL = "http://localhost/magento/api/rest/";
        //final String MAGENTO_REST_API_URL = "http://localhost/magento/api.php?type=rest/";

        // three-legged oauth
                OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                        .provider(MagentoThreeLeggedOAuth.class)
                        .apiKey(MAGENTO_API_KEY)
                        .apiSecret(MAGENTO_API_SECRET)
                        .debug()
                        .build();
                System.out.println("" + service.getVersion());
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Magento's OAuth Workflow");
                System.out.println();
                // Obtain the Request Token
                System.out.println("Fetching the Request Token...");
                Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();
                System.out.println("Got the Request Token!");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Fetching the Authorization URL...");
                String authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken);
                System.out.println("Got the Authorization URL!");
                System.out.println("Now go and authorize Main here:");
                System.out.println(authorizationUrl);
                System.out.println("And paste the authorization code here");
                System.out.print(">>");
                Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
                System.out.println();
                 System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token...");
                    Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
                    System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");
                    System.out.println("(if your curious it looks like this: "
                            + accessToken + " )");
                    System.out.println();

                     OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, MAGENTO_REST_API_URL+ "/products?limit=2");
                        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
                        Response response = request.send();
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println(response.getCode());
                        System.out.println(response.getBody());
                                System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The terminal displays :

```
1.0
Magento's OAuth Workflow

Fetching the Request Token...
obtaining request token from http://`magentohost`/oauth/initiate/
setting oauth_callback to oob
generating signature...
using base64 encoder: CommonsCodec
base string is: POST&http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%2Fmagento%2Foauth%2Finitiate%2F&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dr0ntsryd0hamwmdnjezb8joun01c4h1s%26oauth_nonce%3D2085598405%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1395911858%26oauth_version%3D1.0
signature is: edOifgJQfBg2QoM7ifVBWwvYj30=
appended additional OAuth parameters: { oauth_callback -> oob , oauth_signature -> edOifgJQfBg2QoM7ifVBWwvYj30= , oauth_version -> 1.0 , oauth_nonce -> 2085598405 , oauth_signature_method -> HMAC-SHA1 , oauth_consumer_key -> r0ntsryd0hamwmdnjezb8joun01c4h1s , oauth_timestamp -> 1395911858 }
using Http Header signature
sending request...
response status code: 404
response body: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /magento/oauth/initiate/ was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>

Exception in thread "main" org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /magento/oauth/initiate/ was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
'
    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)
    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:27)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:64)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:40)
    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:45)
    at foo.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Comment: api url return 404 error. it means your api server is not working(http://localhost/magento/api/rest/)

Comment: for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483875/magento-rest-api-error-500

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789938/magento-rest-api-oauth-error/19678803#19678803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. I activated mod_rewrite :http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting/ and did what is said here http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/What+you+need+to+get+started and it worked.